# Guardar imagenes en un .zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una galería de imágenes y estoy dando la posibilidad de que el usuario se descargue todas las imágenes con un botón. Éste botón cuando es presionado llama a una función y se descarga un archivo `.zip` con todas las imágenes.

Las imágenes son guardadas en carpetas, divididas en año / mes / dia.
Pequeño ejemplo: esta la carpeta 2022, dentro carpeta de cada mes (1,2,3,4,5...12), y cada carpeta de mes tiene su carpeta de día ( 01,02,03,04,05...31) y dentro de éstas últimas las imágenes, ya sean .jpg, .png, etc.

Ahora, cuál es el problema? Quiero que se me descargue en un .zip solamente las imagenes, y no las carpetas de las imagenes.

Lo que quiero un `.zip` llamado "Imagenes Hoy" y que dentro solamente contenga .jpg/.png/.jpeg (o cualquier archivo que sea una imagen). ("Mis imagenes" -> .jpg)

Lo que NO quiero (Y lo que me esta pasando) es que se me descarguen las carpetas. ("Mis imagenes"->2022 -> 9 -> 12 -> .jpg)

Este es el metodo que estoy utilizando:

```
public FileResult DescargarImagenes(string pedido)
{
    string consulta;
    List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;
    byte[] bytes;
    ZipFile zip;
    MemoryStream output;

    try
    {
        listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
        consulta = "query";
        listaPedidos = SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

        using (zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
            {
                var archivo_nombre = lista.getPathImagen();
                var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"wwwroot/" + lista.getImagenes());
                zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
            }

            var nombreZip = "ImagenesPedido: " + ViewBag.pedido + ".zip";

            using (output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                zip.Save(output);
                bytes = output.ToArray();
                return File(bytes, "application/zip", nombreZip);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Espero que se haya entendido. Eh intentando agregar `.jpg` a `archivo_arregloBytes` pero no se me ocurre mucho mas, estoy en blanco.

Necesito de su ayuda porfavor.

Comment: dos problemas.. si no guardas las rutas, y hay archivos con el mismo nombre, va a dar error... y luego, no se que libreria estas usando para hacer el zip, pero algunas tenian la posibilidad de eliminar las rutas directamente...

Comment: El nombre de las imagenes no son problema, ya que se los doy con una aplicacion, y para el `.zip` estoy utilizando `Ionic.Zip`

Comment: que pasa si en lugar de usar toda la ruta en archivo_nombre, te quedas solo con el nombre del archivo?

Comment: Dejame probar, ya veo por donde me estas guiando

Comment: Ya está resuelto

Comment: pues entonces pon una respuesta, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creé un `String Array` llamado `nombreImagen`, luego obtuve el directorio de las imágenes, hice un `.Split("/");` de la ruta y lo guardé en `nombreImagen`, y por último a la variable `archivo_nombre` le asigné el resultado de la posición 5 de `nombreImagen`. Esto lo puedo hacer ya que siempre los directorios van a ser:
`wwwroot/imgAndroid/[Año]/[Mes]/[Dia]/[imagen].jpg/.png/.jpeg/etc`, siendo "`[imagen].jpg/.png/.jpeg/etc`" siempre la posición 5.

```
string[] nombreImagen;
foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
 {
      // imgAndroid\2022\09\06\imgas....
      nombreImagen = lista.getPathImagen().Split("/");
      var archivo_nombre = nombreImagen[5];
      var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"wwwroot/" + lista.getImagenes());
      zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
 }
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: 5 horas mas tengo que esperar